# How to call class privat variable inside sockent.on function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sockets

```
  export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  constructor(private notifyService : NotificationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    socket.on("laravel_database_chat:test", function(message){
        //I WANT TO CALL NOTIFICATION SERVICE HERE, BUT NOT WORKING
        this.notifyService.showSuccess();

  });
```

I am trying to call notification service inside socket.io class, but not working.

Comment: in which tutorial i can learn this perfectly, some reference please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change normal function to arrow function to get access to this outside current scope.

```
ngOnInit() {
    socket.on("laravel_database_chat:test", (message) => {
       this.notifyService.showSuccess();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine.  But toaster message not showing properly, sometime it shows and disappear immediately, sometime even not showing